# How do you delete every single element from a page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet that "explodes" your computer after a set period of time. I have everything I need except that I want it to delete everything from the page so that it looks like they have been destroyed from the explosion. This is my current code:

```js
javascript: (() => {
  let rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  function explode() {
    alert('BOOM!');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }

  alert(`Your computer will explode in ${rando} seconds.`);
  setTimeout(explode, rando * 1000);
})();
```

I want to delete all the elements from the page inside of the explode function so that it deletes everything then makes the screen red.

Comment: Just set `document.body.innerHTML = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out in the comments, you can simply overwrite everything in the `<body>` tag with `document.body.innerHTML = "";`. Also, it is possible that `rando` is floored to `0` seconds and the code runs immediately,  which is probably not what you want, so I'd use `Math.ceil()` instead:

```js
(() => {
  let rando = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);

  function explode() {
    alert('BOOM!');
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }

  alert(`Your computer will explode in ${rando} seconds.`);
  setTimeout(explode, rando * 1000);
})();
```

```html
<p>
  test content
</p>
```

Because you tagged your question with [bookmarklet](/questions/tagged/bookmarklet), here's the same code as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(()=>{let rando=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);function explode(){alert('BOOM!');document.body.innerHTML="";document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'}alert(`Your computer will explode in ${ rando } seconds.`);setTimeout(explode,rando*1000)})();
```